# How to Pass Variable value in an argument using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I am implementing a tool on Beyond Compare.
I have this code that reads the content of a file and store in a variable

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%h in ('type C:\user\userfiles\title.txt') do (
set title=%%h
)
```

Example contents of title.txt

```
AAA BBB CCCC
```

Now I want to pass the value of **%title%** in this code

```
%varA% %varB% c:\user\output1\%%a c:\user\output2\%%b "c:\user\report.html" %title% /silent
```

To elavorate:

```
c:\user\output1\%%a    -> %1
c:\user\output2\%%b    -> %2
"c:\user\report.html"  -> %3
%title%                -> %4
```

Now, This files.txt will call the arguments above as a part of the script's arguments.

```
file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-all,line-numbers title:%4 output-to:%3 output-options:html-color %1  %2
```

Now the problem is, when i perform an echo for %title% it displays "AAA BBB CCC" but when on this line of code,

```
%varA% %varB% c:\user\output1\%%a c:\user\output2\%%b "c:\user\report.html" %title% /silent
```

It only reads the first word before the first space which is "AAA"

I already tried to enclosed with double quotes ("%title%") but im getting the ***"The system cannot find the file specified."***

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be calling a procedure with your parameters (but haven't shown us the call) we're forced to make assumptions.

My guess would be:

in the `call` line: ..... "%title%"

Within the procedure, use `%~4` in place of `%4`.

But without knowing what the syntax is of whatever utility may be being used, there's no guarantee.

Comment: It also outputs %~4 as the value. What's wrong with this?

Comment: As I said, we're forced to make assumptions since you haven't shown us the actual code.

Comment: I just summarized the code, but that's the only needed part of the code

Comment: You're not supposed to summarize the code; you're supposed to provide a reproducible example so that we can work on your problem on our own machines. What you've provided won't work by itself.